# Syntax to refer an enum member in a generic class

Tags: c#, java

For the following generic class.

```
class Message<T>
{
    public enum TYPE { Heart, Spade };
}
```

In Java, to refer to enum, I can simply

```
// Works in Java
Message.TYPE type = Message.TYPE.Heart;
```

But how about in C#? In C#, I need to provide a **dummy** type

```
Message<double>.TYPE type = Message<double>.TYPE.Heart;
```

Is there any way I can avoid the `dummy` type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following code.

```
abstract class Message
{
   public enum TYPE { Heart, Spade };
}

class Message<T> : Message
{

}
```

and then you can access `TYPE` like `Message.TYPE type = Message.TYPE.Heart;`

Answer (score 4):

Define the enum separately and not within the class.

**EDIT:**

```
class Message
{
    public enum TYPE { Heart, Spade };
}

class Message<T>: Message
{
}
```

Now you can do it both the ways, usage:

```
Message.TYPE type1 = Message.TYPE.Heart;
Message<double>.TYPE type2 = Message.TYPE.Heart;
```

Hope this would help now.

Comment: That won't work. U can no longer write it this way : `Message.TYPE.Heart`

Comment: I am little confuse. Why is it compulsory to write it this way?

Comment: Design. As TYPE really means message type. Hence, it makes sense to make MessageType part of member of message.

Comment: I have already edited to make it part of Message. See my edited answer.

Comment: Sorry. I have to award Asif, as he is the one who comes out with solution first.